# ffmpeg shell script to squeeze videos for Twitter

Tags: shell, twitter, video

Here's a pretty rookie attempt at creating a shell script to squeeze videos into Twitter's 140s limitation:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    /Applications/ffmpeg -i $f -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=140 / \ 
  $(/Applications/ffprobe -i $f -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0") \
  * PTS[v];[0:a]atempo= \
  $(/Applications/ffprobe -i $f -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0") \
  / 140[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]"  "${f%.*}_twitter.mp4"
done
```

It works, but it's pretty badly written. Can you help me improve it?

1. How can I run ffprobe only once?
2. Do I need ffprobe at all, or does ffmpeg have the duration of the input amongst its arguments?
3. Will it encode faster with other settings (e.g. HW acceleration)?